# Few calculations with huge matrices vs. lots of calculations with small matrices

Tags: java, performance, matrix

I am working on a Java project which has thousands of matrix calculations. But the matrices are at most `10x10` matrices.

I wonder if it is better to use a matrix library or use write the simple functions (`determinant()`, `dotproduct()` etc.) Because when small matrices are used, it is advised not to use libraries but do the operations by custom functions.

I know that matrix libraries like JAMA provides high performance when it comes to `10000x10000` matrices or so.

Instead making 5-6 calculations with `10000x10000` matrices, I make 100000 calculations with `10x10` matrices. Number of primitive operations are nearly the same.

Are both cases same in terms of performance? Should I treat myself as if I'm working with huge matrices and use a library?

Comment: This benchmark could interest you : https://code.google.com/p/java-matrix-benchmark/wiki/RuntimePerformanceBenchmark

Comment: You're correct to assume that optimizing for big n is not the same as small n.  You have to find out if your BLAS library is efficient for small matrices as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect for a 10x10 matrix you won't see much difference.

In tests I have done for hand coding a 4x4 matrix the biggest overhead was loading the data into the L1 cache and how you did it didn't matter very much. For a 3x3 matrix and smaller it did appear to make a significant difference.

Answer (score 2):

**Getting the maximum possible speed (with lots of effort)**

For maximum possible speed I would suggest writing a C function that uses vector math intrinsics such as [Streaming SIMD Extensions (SSE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) or [Advanced Vector Extensions (AVX)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions) operations, together with multithreading (e.g. via OpenMP).

Your Java program would pass all 100k matrices to this native function, which would then handle all the calculations.  Portability becomes an issue, e.g. AVX instructions are only supported on recent CPUs.  Developer effort, especially if you are not familiar with SSE/AVX increases a lot too.

**Reasonable speed without too much effort**

You should use multiple threads by creating a class that extends [java.lang.Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) or implements [java.lang.Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html).  Each thread iterates through a subset of the matrices, calling your maths routine(s) for each matrix.  This part is key to getting decent speed on multi-core CPUs.  The maths could be your own Java function to do the calculations on a single matrix, or you could use a library's functions.

> I wonder if it is better to use a matrix library or use write the
>   simple functions (determinant(), dotproduct() etc.) Because when small
>   matrices are used, it is advised not to use libraries but do the
>   operations by custom functions.
>
> ...
>
> Are both cases same in terms of performance? Should I treat myself as
>   if I'm working with huge matrices and use a library?

No, using a library and writing your own function for the maths are not the same performance-wise.  You may be able to write a faster function that is specialised to your application, but consider this:

- The library functions should have fewer bugs than code you will write.
- A good library will use implementations that are efficient (i.e. least amount of operations).  Do you have the time to research and implement the most efficient algorithms?

You might find the [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) library useful.  I would encourage you to benchmark Apache Commons Math and JAMA to choose the fastest.